# Открыть подробности RecyclerView в новом фрагменте при клике

Tags: android, android-fragment, cardview, recyclerview.adapter

В моем приложений есть `RecyclerView CardView` в фрагменте.
Мне надо чтобы при клике одного из `CardView` открылся новый фрагмент который в нем показывает подробности `CardView`.

***Главный фрагмент:***

```
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment implements IdeaListApadter.ItemClickCallback {

private static final String CARD_TITLE_KEY = "CARD_TITLE_KEY";
private static final String CARD_IMAGE_RES_ID_KEY = "CARD_IMAGE_RES_ID_KEY";
private static final String CARD_TEXT_KEY = "CARD_TEXT_KEY";
IdeaListApadter listData;

public CategoryFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    Context context = getActivity();

    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.idea_recycler_view);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    final IdeaListApadter adapter = new IdeaListApadter(
            new String[]{"Изготовление мебели",
                    "Мини детский сад",
                    "Продажа мороженого",
                    "Организация праздников",
                    "Аренда квартир",
                    "Печатный центр"},
            new int[]{R.drawable.mebel,
                    R.drawable.minidetsad,
                    R.drawable.morozhenoe,
                    R.drawable.prazdnik,
                    R.drawable.arenda,
                    R.drawable.pechat},
            new String[]{
                    "text.",
                    "text.",
                    "text.\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "text.",
                    "text",
                    "text\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "text.",
                    "text.\n" +
                    "text"
                  });

    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
    listData =  adapter;

    listData.setItemClickCallback(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetailsFragment.class);
            intent.putExtra(CategoryFragment.CARD_TITLE_KEY, intent);
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}



@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(int p) {
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(String cardTitle, int cardImageResId, String cardText) {
}
```

}

***Адаптер:***

```
public class IdeaListApadter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<IdeaListApadter.MyViewHolder> {

private String[] mDatasetTitle;
private int[] mDatasetImage;
private String[] mDatasetData;

private ItemClickCallback itemClickCallback;

public interface ItemClickCallback {
    void onItemClick(int p);
    void onItemClick(String cardTitle, int cardImageResId, String cardText);
}

public void setItemClickCallback(final View.OnClickListener itemClickCallback) {
}


public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public CardView cardView;
    public TextView textViewTitle;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public TextView textViewData;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        textViewTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_title);
        imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_image);
        textViewData = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewDetail);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.cont_item_root) {
            int pos = getAdapterPosition();
            itemClickCallback.onItemClick(mDatasetTitle[pos], mDatasetImage[pos], mDatasetData[pos]);
        }
    }
}

public IdeaListApadter(String[] myDataset, int[] ints, String[] strings) {
    mDatasetTitle = myDataset;
    mDatasetImage = ints;
    mDatasetData = strings;
}

@Override
public IdeaListApadter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.idea_card_item, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.textViewTitle.setText(mDatasetTitle[position]);
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(mDatasetImage[position]);
    holder.textViewData.setText(mDatasetData[position]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDatasetTitle.length;
}
```

}

***Второй фрагмент:***

```
public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment{

String ideaTitle;
String ideaData;
int ideaImage;

private TextView card_title, card_text;
private ImageView card_image;

private static final String CARD_TITLE_KEY = "CARD_TITLE_KEY";
private static final String CARD_IMAGE_RES_ID_KEY = "CARD_IMAGE_RES_ID_KEY";
private static final String CARD_TEXT_KEY = "CARD_TEXT_KEY";

public static DetailsFragment newInstance(String cardTitle, int cardImageResId, String cardText) {
    DetailsFragment detailsFragment = new DetailsFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(CARD_TITLE_KEY, cardTitle);
    bundle.putInt(CARD_IMAGE_RES_ID_KEY, cardImageResId);
    bundle.putString(CARD_TEXT_KEY, cardText);
    detailsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return detailsFragment;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.idea_detail_layout, container, false);

    card_title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_title);
    card_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idea_detail);
    card_image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_image);

    ideaTitle = getArguments().getString("CARD_TITLE_KEY");
    ideaImage = getArguments().getInt("CARD_IMAGE_RES_ID_KEY");
    ideaData = getArguments().getString("CARD_TEXT_KEY");

    return view;
}

public void change(String ideaTitle, String ideaData, int ideaImage){
    card_title.setText(ideaTitle);
    card_text.setText(ideaData);
    card_image.setImageResource(ideaImage);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Всё очень просто. В адаптере, где вы задаете значения для ваших `TextView

Вот тут

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textViewTitle.setText(mDatasetTitle[position]);
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(mDatasetImage[position]);
        holder.textViewData.setText(mDatasetData[position]);
    }
```

Добавьте событие клика либо для всей вьюшки или для текста.
Например на своем примере покажу. Где я вызываю фрагмент и передаю данные

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public
        void onClick(final View view) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
            Fragment_texnika_adapter_test fragment_texnika_adapter = new Fragment_texnika_adapter_test();
            fragmentTransaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment_texnika_adapter);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putParcelable("statictika", model.getTexnika_sobr()); //Указываю что буду передавать
            fragment_texnika_adapter.setArguments(bundle);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            mListener.onContentItemClicked(model);
        }
    });
```

Во фрагменте я получаю данные

```
public class Fragment_texnika_adapter_test  extends Fragment{
     private Texnika_Sobr texnika_sobr;
     //Ваши данные (Кнопки, тексты и т.д)

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_texnika_statistika_adapter, container, false);
     Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            texnika_sobr = bundle.getParcelable("statictika");
        }
//Ваш код
return view;
}
```

В моем случае я передаю класс. Для этого его нужно имплементировать `Parcelable`. Для этого есть онлайн генератор [Parcelable](http://www.parcelabler.com/), туда вставляете свой класс и генерируете новый.